# Use HTTP Digest Authentication with WSO2 ESB

Tags: proxy, wso2, digest, digest-authentication, wso2-esb

Is there a way to create a proxy or API with WSO2-ESB which calls a service secured with HTTP Digest authentication ?

I can't find anything on the documentation.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WSO2 ESB supports authentication based on Basic authentication credentials
Out of the bo. However WSO2 ESB do not provide support for "HTTP digest Authentication".

As a solution you can implementation for "HTTP digest authentication" then you can plug them in to synapse config as [Class Mediator](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Class+Mediator)

Comment: Thank you Vanji,
From what I understand, Class Mediator only deals with query headers and body, so what should I do in that custom class ?
Do I need to query the digest-secured service in that class in order to build the correct header ?

Comment: Yes, by class mediator you are intersecting the mediation flow and make use of the existing payload and headers to  perform your "HTTP digest authentication" logic.